# embeddings of TVS are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

How to show that the two embeddings of TVS are continuous:

$C^{\infty}_c\subset S\subset C^{\infty}$?

According to Wikipedia, the definition of "Continuously embedded" is that " one normed vector space is said to be continuously embedded in another normed vector space if the inclusion function between them is continuous". Is this the correct idea to follow?

EDIT: $S$ is the Schwartz space,  $C^{\infty}$ is the space of smooth functions, and $C^{\infty}_c$ is the space of smooth functions whose support are compact.

The topology on $S$ is the normed topology:
[image]

And I really do not know what topology we should impose on the other 2 spaces...

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is the correct defintion. On the other hand, can you specify what are $C_c^\infty$, $S$ and $C^\infty$?

Comment: Hi, I have added the definitions of the spaces...

Comment: you have to specify the norm (the topology) that's all the point !

Comment: I only know the topology on $S$, but I have no idea on the topology used on the other 2 spaces...

Comment: If you treat $C^\infty_c$ as a subset of $S$, then the inclusion $C^\infty_c \subset S$ is continuous.

Comment: @JohnMa , Hi can you explain why?

Comment: I mean if the norm of $C^\infty_c$ is given by that of $S$, then the inclusion is continuous.

Comment: With $X\subset Y$, a topology $T_x$ on $X$, and a topology $T_y$ on $Y$, the embedding $id_X:X\to Y$ is continuous from $(X,T_x)$ into $(Y,T_y)$ if and only if  $\{t\cap X: t\in T_y\}\subset T_x\}.$  In other words, the topology $T_x$ is stronger than, or equal to the subspace topology on $X$ induced by $T_y$. In particular, if $T_y$ is generated by a metric $d_y$ and if $T_x$ is generated by a metric $d_x$,  then the condition $\forall p.q\in X \; (d_y(p,q)\leq d_x(p,q) \; )$ is sufficient to imply that the embedding is continuous